# How to set up customized project type?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to ask how to create a customized project type in Eclipse. For example, when I create my project, a project with some built-in read-only folders will appear and in these folders, some files are added. Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a New project wizard using the extension point org.eclipse.ui.newWizards.

Then in the implementation you could rely on an existing wizard (look the plug-in spy to get the contributor plug-in of the wizard you are using - select the contribution of the first page in the New wizard, and press Alt+Shift+F3), and override the performFinish method to create your own content. However, you could also create your brand new wizard.

For creating the project/contents, you have to use the Eclipse resources API. A quick tutorial is included in the [Java AST tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html) of Lars Vogel - it is Java specific, but has some information about creating files/folders.

Comment: Hi Zoltan, thank you for your answer. I still have questions about your approach. Firstly, using the plug-in spy (by the way Alt+Shift+F3 instead of Alt+Shift+3?) only gives me the contributing class id (org.eclipse.ui.ide) but not the contributing wizard id for the purpose of overriding. Could you be more specific about how to reuse an existing wizard and just override one of its method?

Comment: You cannot override the wizard by ID. However, you could open the corresponding plugin.xml, and there manually search for the wizard extension, and its implementation class (sadly, I know of no better way). Then you can override this class in your plug-in, and then reference it in a different wizard extension. Thanks for pointing out the typo of the hotkey, I update my answer with it.